Are these called sweetener pills in AmE? Or just sweeteners?

Is a white pill used as a substitute for sugar like the ones in the picture called a sweetener pill or just a sweetener in American English?

They're tablets, not pills. Pills are for medicine. Cognate with German tablette.  Sweetener tablets.

Thank you very much.

I’m an American, and I don’t think I’ve ever seen artificial sweetener tablets before. We have powders but I didn’t know about the tablets.

I tried googling "suss stoff" and got "sugar substitute." The best approach is probably to dissociate the product from its form and say that these are "sugar substitute in tablet form," or just "sugar substitute tablets."

I'm not familiar with that particular brand, but I always call such things simply, "fake sugar". Like at restaurants I'll ask, "Do you have fake sugar, like Splenda or Equal?"
As others note, if I had to specify the form, I'd call them "tablets". In the US fake sugar usually comes as a powder or granules, and usually in packets measure to have equivalent sweetness to 1 teaspoon of sugar.

Thank you very much.

The complete sentence would be "...sweetener tablet".  But people always shorten things. so "...I use sweetener in my tea" is perfectly acceptable.
